Can i bank a shares dividends cheque thats in someone elses name?
My father receives dividends from a company by cheque thats in USD. His bank does not do currency conversion so therefore he asks me to bank it at my bank as if they were my dividends and because we have the same name.
Is this breaking any law in the UK?

What he would normally have done to n the past is sign the check over to you. Even in this case, I would suggest doing so, since that gets his signature on the check acknowledging the transfer. If it isn't signed over, you may find yourself being investigated for elder abuse, since children have been known to steal from their parents. You would be especially at risk if the check carries the address and he does not live with you, of course. And yes, if investigated you have an explanation that he will support you in, but the process is not pleasant.

also, tax laws.

Since keshlam and littleadv are both so clearly right and you have no ulterior motive, why are you not asking your bank?
